# Append if key exists or create new in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a huge excel sheet with fields:

- Customer_id
- activity
- timestamp

I have to read that excel sheet and insert values into the collection. If the document with the key of given **customer_id** exists then activity should be appended to activities key otherwise, a new document should be created. 
Do I need to check for every **customer_id** for existence before inserting? What is the efficient way to do that?

Comment: you can use update function and pass upsert as true.
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using upsert with $push combination. Please see the following example

```
 record = {customerId: 1, activity: 'Activity1.1'}
db.tempc.update({_id: record.customerId}, {$push: {activities: record.activity}}, {upsert: true})
```

Then observe result

```
db.tempc.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "activities" : [ "Activity1.1" ] }
```

Then try processing second record which has same customerId, but different activity

```
record = {customerId: 1, activity: 'Activity1.2'}
db.tempc.update({_id: record.customerId}, {$push: {activities: record.activity}}, {upsert: true})
```

Now observe that this activity being added to existing customer

```
db.tempc.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "activities" : [ "Activity1.1", "Activity1.2" ] }
```